# EF Core Many-to-many table to another table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have a question regarding Many to Many tables using EF Core.

Assume I have the below situation:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}  
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}  
public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Now, assume that I want to have another table called "Contracts" which should be a child of "BookCategory".

How can I create this relationship?

Comment: Adding a relationship on `BookCategory`, that is not a `Book` or a `Category` seems to me like you're trying to do something that should not be done. `Contracts` does not belong in `BookCategory`. But if you must do it, follow the same principle you used when configuring the relationship between book and bookcategory.

Comment: Do you really have contracts per book *and* category?